# Probability of drawing three cards, with the third being a King

Tags: probability, combinatorics

CONTEXT: First year university statistics course exercise

If $C$ is the number of cards drawn from a deck of 52 cards until a King
is drawn, find $\mathbb P(C = 3)$. I'm not 100% sure how to do this question.

This would mean the first and second cards are not Kings but the third is.

Let $A$ be the event that you draw two non-Kings and then a King.
$|A| = {48 \choose 1}{47 \choose 1}{4 \choose 1}$.

The sample space $\Omega$ would be any three card selections. $|\Omega|={52 \choose 1}{51 \choose 1}{50 \choose 1}$

By the equilikely principle, this means $\mathbb P(C = 3)=\frac{{48 \choose 1}{47 \choose 1}{4 \choose 1}}{{52 \choose 1}{51 \choose 1}{50 \choose 1}}$?

Any help would be greatly appreciated (I'm finding it difficult to check my counting answers!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your answer and reasoning is correct, but sometimes it's easier to think about the events separately; you have three independent events, P(not King 1st draw), P(not King 2nd draw | no King on 1st) and then P(King | no King on 1st or 2nd draws) and the final probability is just these multiplied together.

$$\frac{48\choose{1}}{52\choose{1}}\times\frac{47\choose{1}}{51\choose{1}}\times\frac{4\choose{1}}{50\choose{1}}$$

I know it's equivalent but I find it helps even just thinking about it in a slightly different way.

Answer (score 1):

$\color{olive}\checkmark$ Yes, that is okay.

You want the probability for obtaining *two from forty-eight* non-kings and then *one from four* kings, when selecting *two from fifty-two* cards and then *one from fifty* remaining cards.

$$\dfrac{\dbinom{48}2\dbinom 41}{\dbinom{52}2\dbinom {50}1} =\dfrac{48\cdot 47\cdot 4~~}{52\cdot 51\cdot 50}$$